# Chrome DevTools output is empty?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Suddenly there is no output from expressions made directly in console?

OSX, Version 30.0.1599.101

Example:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oops, sorry. Had 'error' selected in the filter - switched to 'all' and everything is fine.